# How to get the XML node which is not a parent of the current node using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

In my result file I need to copy contents from 1st XML i.e. the `<INSTANCE>` tag details for site tags which is always one line above the `<site>` tag.

In my case I have details of each site tags in the 2nd sample file, for each site tag, I need to get the one tag above i.e INSTANCETAG for example in my case using PowerShell.

1st sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigDetails>
<INSTANCE Name="USASERVER"/>
<site id = "123">
  <address = "USA"/>
</site>
<INSTANCE Name="EUROPESERVER"/>
<site id = "156">
  <address = "EU"/>
</site>
<INSTANCE Name="CHINASERVER"/>
<site id = "293">
  <address = "China"/>
</site>
</ConfigDetails>
```

2nd sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigDetails>
<!--Respective INSTANCETAG SHOULD COPIED FROM 1st XML FILE-->
<site id = "123">
  <address = "USA"/>
</site>
<!--Respoective INSTANCETAG SHOULD COPIED FROM 1st XML FILE-->
<site id = "293">
  <address = "China"/>
</site>
</ConfigDetails>
```

Comment: What you tired so far?

Comment: Start with [xml]$doc= get-content -path $xmlpath

Then you can use Where-object, or Select-xml

Comment: Hi @MahmoodShehab, Is that possible a sample snippet how to use that ?I have used the get-content -path $ xmlpath. And using a for-each loop i am able to iterate the Site tags. So while i iterate each site tag i need to copy the instance tag from the 1st xml file and paste the one above tag.

Comment: Defining an XML format that relies on the sequence of elements is a *terrible* idea. Don't ever do that. XML is by design a hierarchical format, so the `<INSTANCE>` nodes should *contain* the `<site>` nodes, not precede them.